# wordpress - media library category URL structure

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets, media-library

I am looking for a solution that would enable me to create an URL / permalink structure for the Wordpress Media Library.

So I need a solution (plugin or a code snippet) that could create different categories / folders for the media library, but also modify the URL accordingly.

Is there such a thing??

Other than a few outdated plugins, I really can't find any reference at all.

Comment: try iTheme security. It has the ability to change the `wp-content` folder. That means you can change the media library from `yourwebsite/wp-content/uploads/` to `yourwebsite/custom-foldername/uploads/`

Is this what your are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @Speir , I can actually achieve the exact same thing by modifying the wp-confi.php file to define the media folder, but that's not what I'm after.

I can find many plugins that create a folder structure to the media library, but none of them will also change the URL. So I need to create an additional category for media library, for example BOOKS, MAGAZINES etc, but then have the permalink modified too, so for example wp-uploads/books , wp-uploads/magazines etc.